# ¿Cómo usar between con variables en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Intento usar `between` en variables, para simular un rango de fechas, tengo algo de este estilo.

```
CREATE PROC FECHAS
@MES NVARCHAR(2)
AS 
SELECT * FROM TABLA
WHERE MONTH(FECHA) BETWEEN @MES AND @MES
```

Comment: Estas usando una sola variable `@MES` deberías tener otra variable

Comment: Cierto!! Gracias @VictorPerdomo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas evaluando con una sola variable, deberías tener 2 variables una `Fecha Inicio` y otra que sea la `Fecha Fin` para poder tener un rango de fechas.

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROC GET_FECHAS
@MES_INICIO INT,
@MES_FINAL INT
AS 
SELECT * FROM TABLA
WHERE MONTH(FECHA) BETWEEN @MES_INICIO AND @MES_FINAL
--AND YEAR(FECHA) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```